# is it OK to join 2 tables based on 2 ID columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Tb1

```
ID1 - ID2 - other columns....
12 - 25 - xxxx
24 - 63 - xxx
.....
```

And Tb2

```
ID1 - ID2 - other columns....
12 - 25 - xxxx
34 - 65 - xxx
.....
```

Now I want to join these 2 tables based on 2 ID columns.

```
Select * from tb1
Join tb2
on tb1.ID1=tb2.ID1 and tb1.ID2=tb2.ID2
```

My quest is, is it Ok to do that, is there any problem if I design DB that way? For some reason, I can't make 1 ID column.

Also how the join work? 1st it joins the ID1 & then it uses the result to join ID2?

Comment: yes you can. whether it makes sense to do so will depend on how you designed your schema.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to do so. By the way, I doubt you actually want **everything** (`SELECT *`).

Comment: but how the join work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is perfectly acceptable, and is often found in joins to `many:many` relationships in [junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

The scenario you've described (the need to join 2 tables on 2 common columns) would occur if another table needed to reference a row in the `many:many` table.

Consider the following contrived example where the junction table `PersonPhoto` - { a person can have many photos, a photo can be of many people} - needs to be referenced by an audit table. It can be seen that both `PersonId` and `PhotoId` would need to be retained in the referencing table, to identity which row had been modified for the purpose of an audit:

[image: Junction Table being referenced]

Hence, any time a join is needed between the table `PersonPhoto` and `PersonPhotoAudit`, both columns `PhotoId` and `PersonId` would need to be joined in both tables.

SqlFiddle of the DDL : [MySql here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a94b) and [SqlServer here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e28f9)

If the combination `PhotoId` and `PersonId` are unique on `PersonPhoto`, the pair can be turned into a [compound (or composite)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/in-sql-is-it-composite-or-compound-keys) primary key. Foreign keys to this compound key would need to include both columns.

The alternative (to having both key columns in both tables) is to create a new surrogate primary key on the junction table (e.g. `PersonPhotoID INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (PersonPhotoID)`). Then only this surrogate key would need to be referenced in referencing tables like `PersonPhotoAudit`).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, you may really need two ID columns to identify a specific row (depending on the data, of course).
If this is indeed the case, I see no problem with having these same two identifiers in multiple tables, and joining according to them.

Comment: but how the join work? 1st it joins the ID1  & then it uses that result to join ID2?

Comment: @Tum I don't understand this question - it just joins rows that match both IDs.

Comment: @Tum yup, simplicity at its finest. :-)